# MySQL IN clause in where condition is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with name products one of it's column name is design_id in which design id's are save in comma separated format like - 5,4,6,51,85,65,98,32,324,122,14,755,

I have to find results which have design id 98. And for this, I have written a query

```
SELECT * FROM `products` where `design_id` IN (98)
```

The query is running successfully but not returning any results ?

Column type is varchar.

Comment: the `IN` operator works the other way around

Comment: What kind of field is it? int or String with comma seperated?

Comment: Yes i am fetching it.

Comment: @almasshaikh it is number with comma , separated.

Comment: @user3616586 so are you saying it's a string?

Comment: If you can post your table, this would be easier to understand because  I have no idea what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="SELECT Lastname,Age FROM Persons ORDER BY Lastname";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Fetch one and one row
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row[0],$row[1]);
    }
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The IN operator walks through a dataset, so you have to reverse the query.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE 98 IN column_name
```

However the equal opterator is much faster in most databases.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name=98
```

Comment: i can't use such type its dynamic portion and we not to assumed how many column we have to create.My column structure is 5,45,455,38,26,75,45,

Comment: SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE 98 IN (5,45,455,38,26,75,45)

Answer (score 1):

Is better use for `SELECT * FROM table_name where column_name='98'`

But is you want to store:

Try use **`INSERT`**:

`INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);`

But is you want to fetch:

Try use **`mysql_fetch_row`**:

Example :

```
 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="SELECT Lastname,Age FROM Persons ORDER BY Lastname";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Fetch one and one row
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n",$row[0],$row[1]);
    }
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```